# Does assignment operator work internally like their arithmetic equivalents?

Tags: java, operators, bytecode

Consider the following code:

```
short x = 1;  

x += 1;    // all good
x = x + 1; // error, since (x + 1) returns int
```

**The question is:**

Is it safe to say that internally Java automatically cast `x` to `int`, then back to `short`? Something like this:

```
x += 1 will be expand to x = (short) ((int) x + 1);
```

The same question about the rest of the assignment operators: `+= -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=`

Comment: From the Specs: *A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.*

Answer (score 0):

In compound assignment operator type-casting is automatically done by compile.